# Google+ login, fetching user data using new google services

Tags: android, google-plus

I am implementing login with google using the new google services version 4.2, I am creating my google client as follows:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

With only SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN it does not work- internal error. However I can login using this ApiClient and following the instructions found at google. But whenever I am trying to access any information via

```
Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)
```

The object is empty, I have added my SHA-1 key to my console, and have no idea what could go wrong.
Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 0):

Try with this method:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_GPLUS = 9000;
private static final String TAG_GPLUS = "google";
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialogGplus;
private PlusClient mPlusClient;
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(SignUpActiivty.this, callbacks,
            connectionFailedListener).setActions(
            "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
            "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
    // .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE) // recommended login scope
    // for social features
            .build();
    mProgressDialogGplus = new ProgressDialog(SignUpActiivty.this);
    mProgressDialogGplus.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialogGplus.setMessage("Signing in...");
    mProgressDialogGplus.show();

    mPlusClient.connect();
```

Methods:
1. ConnectionCallbacks callbacks = new ConnectionCallbacks() {

```
    public void onDisconnected() {

        Log.v(TAG_GPLUS, "disconnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.v(TAG_GPLUS, "onConnected");

        mProgressDialogGplus.dismiss();

        String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
        Toast.makeText(SignUpActiivty.this, accountName + " is connected.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson() != null) {
            Person currentPerson = mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson();
            saveGooglePlusUserData(currentPerson);

        }
    }
};
```

2. OnConnectionFailedListener connectionFailedListener = new OnConnectionFailedListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.v(TAG_GPLUS, "onConnectionFailed result = " + result);
        if (mProgressDialogGplus.isShowing()) {
            // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
            // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
            // connection dialog.
            if (result.hasResolution()) {
                Log.v(TAG_GPLUS,
                        "onConnectionFailed result.hasResolution() = "
                                + result);
                try {
                    result.startResolutionForResult(SignUpActiivty.this,
                            REQUEST_CODE_GPLUS);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }

        // Save the intent so that we can start an activity when the user
        // clicks the sign-in button.
        mConnectionResult = result;
    }
};
```

In onActivityResult :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.v(TAG, "requestCode = " + requestCode + " resultCode = "
            + resultCode);
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GPLUS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.v(TAG, "requestCode = " + requestCode + " resultCode = "
                + resultCode);
        mConnectionResult = null;
        mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(SignUpActiivty.this,
                callbacks, connectionFailedListener).setActions(
                "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity").build();
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }
}
```

And method saveGooglePlusUserData is:

```
 private void saveGooglePlusUserData(Person currentPerson) {
        int gender_id = currentPerson.getGender();
        Person.Name name = currentPerson.getName();
        String account_id = currentPerson.getId();
        String email = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
        String bDate = currentPerson.getBirthday();
        int ageGroup = countGPlusUserAge(bDate);
        // Person.Name name = {"familyName":"surname","givenName":"Name"}
        // BirthDate = 1988-04-24

        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(name.toString());
            firstName = jObj.getString("givenName");
            lastName = jObj.getString("familyName");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v(TAG_GPLUS, "FirstName = " + firstName + " Name = " + name);
        Log.v(TAG_GPLUS, "LastName = " + lastName);
        Log.v(TAG_GPLUS, "Account_id = " + account_id);
        Log.v(TAG_GPLUS, "Email = " + email);
        Log.v(TAG_GPLUS, "Gender ID = " + gender_id);
        Log.v(TAG_GPLUS, "BirthDate = " + bDate);


    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Does not work. Seems that my key is not valid. Logcat outputs that I have GLS error: INVALID_KEY, however I have no green idea how to fix it.

Comment: What is the gender id for male and female?

Comment: gender ID = 1 is for Male and another is for Female

Answer (score 0):

When I used `SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE` it would connect but I would get nothing when I used both scopes it would do the same and when I used just the login it wouldn't connect. For me the reason was because I changed my package name and I didn't change it in the client id on google developers console. You might not have exactly the same situation but try to check if your client id info is correct.